# How I can apply force in chipmunk

Tags: iphone, chipmunk

How I can use this function

Im try but there are error or warning

```
setupchipmunk(){
........
}

update(){

if(touch==true){

cpBodyApplyForce(body1,cpv(val1,val2),cpv(val3,val4));

}
}
```

when touch begin in console I found this error

warning: Ignored unknown object module at 0x0 with type 0x5dd334

warning: Couldn't find minimal symbol for "_sigtramp" - backtraces may be unreliable

please any help

Answer (score 0):

You can apply force using:

```
body->f = cpv(dx, dy);
```

Good luck